# In KDE, how to get the Application Menu (File, Edit...) back on top of each window?

Tags: kde, plasma, menu

[image]

My File, Edit... Menus are gone from the Dolphin file manager. For the life of me I cant figure out how to get it back. Thank you.

Comment: At leas in some applications, Ctrl + M toggles the menu bar. Not sure this will work in your case (nor I can find a global setting for that at the moment).

Comment: Yes, but that does not seem to work with file manage Dolphin :(

Comment: That's weird, Dolphin is actually the application I was testing it with. I can't be sure, but you may be able edit the file `~/.config/dolphinrc` (when no Dolphin window is open), locating the `[MainWindow]` section and changing `MenuBar=Disabled` into `MenuBar=Enabled`. The next Dolphin window you open should have a menu bar, and you can then open Settings → Configure Keyboard Shortcuts and make sure "Ctrl+M" is bound to "Show Menubar". You may also want to check whether "Ctrl+M" is bound to something else in System Settings → Shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

You can press the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + M. [Here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=223&t=101281) you can also find more information on a discussion on this issue.

Comment: The link is dead.